# What is the difference between "submit" and "deposit"?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

I am trying to find out the difference between "submit" and "deposit" these words are very confusing when you visit to a bank and somebody ask you "what is the purpose of you to come here and you replied that "I came here to submit money" or "I came here to deposit money" out of these two sentences which is correct and why?

Comment: Which dictionary or dictionaries did you look these words up in, and what specific thing about their meanings do you not understand?

Comment: Banda online lagda. :P. Dekhi, khap payie. Kise nu samajh ini ana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *submit* something to someone is to offer it for the recipient's approval: you *submit* a scholarly article to an academic journal, you *submit* a proposal to a prospective client, you *submit* your resumé to a prospective employer.

Ordinarily you do not *submit* your money to a bank; they are eager to have it and are very unlikely to reject it, unless you are a known associate of drug dealers or terrorists.

To *deposit* something somewhere is literally to put it there, and that is what you do at the bank: you put your money in and eventually (all too soon!) take it out again.

Comment: How about, "_I've to submit my college fee by 5th January, 2015_ ". We are not seeking for any kind of approval here.

Comment: @user31782 This use arose in the 1940s as an error for *remit*, and has in the last generation become widely used among those receiving or demanding payments as a euphemism for *pay*; it is at best business/bureaucratic jargon and should be avoided. "I have to pay my fee by Jan 5."

Answer (score 1):

You deposit money: give it to the bank for safekeeping and to gain interest.

See collins dictionary here:

[deposit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deposit?showCookiePolicy=true)

[submit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/submit?showCookiePolicy=true)

Comment: Welcome to ELL, by the way!